# What is the approach to render CellTable and SimplePager with data from RESTful/Ajax source?

Tags: java, gwt

The backend in which the GWT app interface through REST can return the total number of records in the database, GWT can query with Skip and Limit.

What is the approach to render CellTable and SimplePager with data from RESTful source? Meaning pagination based on the total number of rows in the database, from my understanding the SimplePager creates a pagination widget based on the total number of rows already in the CellTable, in what way it can be possible to make CellTable render data from a RESTful API and at the same time the SimplePager to be able to page the table given that kind of datasource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The REST service is an [`AsyncDataProvider`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/view/client/AsyncDataProvider.html). You could start with example code provided in the documentation.

The general approach is as follows:

```
table.addRangeChangeHandler(new RangeChangeEvent.Handler() {
    @Override
    public void onRangeChange(RangeChangeEvent event) {
        int start = event.getNewRange().getStart();
        int length = event.getNewRange().getLength();
        // get data from REST service
    }
});
```

When you get data from the service you need both: total row count and actual data to be displayed on the current page. Set new data in the provider:

```
provider.updateRowCount(totalRowCount, true);
provider.updateRowData(start, values);
```